# Conditional resource inclusion/exclusion for Android apk build

Tags: android, android-resources, apk

I keep coming back to this problem, since there doesn't seem to be a clean solution.  Does anyone have a good strategy to exclude resources from a child project in Android?

I have two scenarios:

1 - Base library project has localization files for en, es, etc.

--Child project 1 uses all localizations, and everything is good

--Child project 2 is only localized to English, but the final .apk would have a partial localization due to the parent resources (although ADT19 or so added Lint rules to warn/prevent you from doing this).

The only solution I have to this right now is to have a separate parent library for the localization, and only include it in child project 1.  This is a big pain if you have lots of library projects.

2 - Exclusion of build-specific resources.  I have a few images that are only needed for my Nook-specific builds of my apps, which are triggered by a flag.  Conditional code works great, but the resources are always included.

I'd prefer not to create yet another child project for EVERY ONE of my apps.  Is there any way to set a build/compile flag to prune specific image resources out so they don't get into the final .apk?

The second problem may be specific to me, but I'm surprised that I can't find any good discussion on the first point.  Are no other devs localizing only some apps?  Or are most folks just ignoring the issue?

Comment: I've seen talk on adding files to an .apk, but I'm looking for something a little more like ProGuard - automatic and built into the tools rather than hacking the final .apk.

Comment: Your scenarios are doable by using external build tools like Ant or Maven, both provide abilities to fine-control every single step during build process (compile, dex, packaging and etc). if using Maven, exclude resources is pretty easy via [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html).

Comment: I may need to go that way.  I was hoping for a cleaner (and ideally simpler) solution, though.

Comment: Have you figured out where and how to adjust the ANT files? I have the same problem (first topic) and if you already tried it maybe you can give me some pointers in the right direction. Otherwise I have to dig into the ANT scripts myself.

Comment: I have pulled the language resources into a separate library project, and only include it with child projects that need them.  I haven't had the chance to muck with the Ant scripts yet.

Comment: For anyone battling this issue in 2015, it'll be much easier.  Android studio handles dependencies better with Gradle, and you can limit which languages are included in the build.gradle file - see Res Configs here https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Base library project has localization files for en, es, etc.

You have two projects using this library, and only one of them needs all the translations. Hence, those translations could be in the project using the library and needing the translations, not in the library itself. This is no different than any other project customizing resources of a library (e.g., replacing icons, replacing layouts).

Now, once you start getting into more complicated mixes (e.g., two projects need the translations and a third does not), then you start running into problems.

> Exclusion of build-specific resources. I have a few images that are only needed for my Nook-specific builds of my apps, which are triggered by a flag. Conditional code works great, but the resources are always included.

Xav and I chatted a bit about conditional resources [in this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30895). His focus is on debug vs. production (resource equivalent to `BuildConfig.DEBUG`), but it sounds like something more flexible is a possibility.

Both of these things could be handled by a custom release build script. In normal debug builds, you'd leave it all alone; in a production build, have an Ant script work off a copy of the project, trimming out directories that are not needed, before compiling, signing, and zipaligning.

Comment: That's what I've done for project3, which has a one-off translation to Italian (and therefore a few strings_libx.xml files corresponding to parent libs).  My tree of libs and apps is getting more complex, though, and I am displeased with adding complexity (maintenance complexity due to duplicated strings files, or workspace complexity with LibX to split language resources out).  I think the writing may be on the wall though - I need to dig deeper into the tools and script some actions to prune the output.

Comment: I still haven't found the time to build some Ant scripts, but I'm starting to think that really is the right solution.  As my needs get more complex, there's no substitute for the flexibility of my own scripts.  I don't think the DEBUG flag will offer enough ability to configure.  Also, if I wait long enough, the new Android build system with Gradle will be finalized and I can just learn that: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system