# Remove unused resources from appcompat

Tags: android

In the latest update of appcompat Google added resources for xxhdpi devices. So my app size increased by ~100 kb.

Actually I don't use most of this resources (pngs) in my app. How can I exclude this files from the final apk?

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing the AppCompat project, you can go directly to the resources location and delete the files. But consider that 100 kb is nearly nothing for an APK. And in a near future, you might need those resources, having in consideration that screen devices are getting bigger and screen densities too.

Comment: yes you are right. I don't want to remove resources manually. My goal is to automatically exclude unused resources from the final apk.

Comment: ok. check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301994/conditional-resource-inclusion-exclusion-for-android-apk-build

Comment: Thanks :) Will try a bit later